# XNA animated button

Tags: c#, button, xna, animated

I am currently making game and i got stuck making the menue. I finished most of it but ther is one thing i can't solve on my own... i made a button class:

```
public class Button
{
    public Texture2D texture1;
    Texture2D texture2;
    Texture2D texture3;
    Vector2 position;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    public Vector2 size;
    public bool isMousOver;
    public bool isClicked;
    public bool isPressed;
    public Button(int texture1, int texture2, int texture3, int position_x, int position_y)
    {
        this.texture1 = Game_class.menue[texture1];
        this.texture2 = Game_class.menue[texture2];
        this.texture3 = Game_class.menue[texture3];
        this.position.X = position_x;
        this.position.Y = position_y;
        this.isMousOver = false;
        this.isClicked = false;
        this.isPressed = false;
        this.size = new Vector2(Game_class.menue[texture1].Width / 2, Game_class.menue[texture1].Height / 2);
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);
    }
    public Button(int texture1, int texture2, int texture3, int position_x, int position_y, float x, float y)
    {
        this.texture1 = Game_class.menue[texture1];
        this.texture2 = Game_class.menue[texture2];
        this.texture3 = Game_class.menue[texture3];
        this.position.X = position_x;
        this.position.Y = position_y;
        this.isMousOver = false;
        this.isClicked = false;
        this.isPressed = false;
        this.size = new Vector2(Game_class.menue[texture1].Width / x, Game_class.menue[texture1].Height / y);
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);
    }
    public void Update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {
            this.isMousOver = true;
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                isPressed = true;
                this.isClicked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.isClicked = false;
                isPressed = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.isMousOver = false;
            this.isClicked = false;
        }
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (isMousOver == true)
        {
            if (isPressed == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture3, rectangle, Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture2, rectangle, Color.White); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture1, rectangle, Color.White);
        }

    }
}
```

as you can see my button uses 3 different textures. One for the normal-state, one for the MouseOver-State and the last one for the isClicked-state. The problem now is everything is working except the isCklicked state. I know how to solve it but not exatcly how to realize it... the problem is that the button should do its click-event after i released the left mouse button, not by clicking it... so there will be enough time for the icClicked animation and it will stop doing the click-event as long as the button is clicked, because this makes it hard to choose a option to be eiher on or off...

So i just need a way to tell the game to stay ready when the button is clicked and only playing the click event after releasing the button, if you know what i mean.

So, any idears?

PS: Sorry for my bad english but i hope i could tell you my problem in an understandable way ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
public void Update(MouseState mouse)
{
    MouseState lastmousestate, currentmousestate;

    lastmousestate = currentmousestate;    
    currentmousestate = Mouse.GetState();

    Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
    if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
    {
        this.isMousOver = true;
         if (lastmousestate.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && currentmousestate.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            isPressed = true;
            this.isClicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.isClicked = false;
            isPressed = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.isMousOver = false;
        this.isClicked = false;
    }
}
```

If it solves the problem make sure to come back and mark the answer as correct so others can benefit from your question :)

This is the complete Button-Class with the correctly working code:

```
public class Button
{
    public Texture2D texture1;
    MouseState currentMouseState;
    MouseState lastMouseState;
    Texture2D texture2;
    Texture2D texture3;
    Vector2 position;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    public Vector2 size;
    public bool isMousOver;
    public bool isClicked;
    public bool isPressed;
    public Button(int texture1, int texture2, int texture3, int position_x, int position_y)
    {
        this.texture1 = Game_class.menue[texture1];
        this.texture2 = Game_class.menue[texture2];
        this.texture3 = Game_class.menue[texture3];
        this.position.X = position_x;
        this.position.Y = position_y;
        this.isMousOver = false;
        this.isClicked = false;
        this.isPressed = false;
        this.size = new Vector2(Game_class.menue[texture1].Width / 2, Game_class.menue[texture1].Height / 2);
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);
    }
    public Button(int texture1, int texture2, int texture3, int position_x, int position_y, float x, float y)
    {
        this.texture1 = Game_class.menue[texture1];
        this.texture2 = Game_class.menue[texture2];
        this.texture3 = Game_class.menue[texture3];
        this.position.X = position_x;
        this.position.Y = position_y;
        this.isMousOver = false;
        this.isClicked = false;
        this.isPressed = false;
        this.size = new Vector2(Game_class.menue[texture1].Width / x, Game_class.menue[texture1].Height / y);
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);
    }
    public void Update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
        lastMouseState = currentMouseState;
        currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {
            this.isMousOver = true;
            if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed || lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                isPressed = true;
                if (lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    this.isClicked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.isClicked = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isPressed = false;
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.isMousOver = false;
            this.isClicked = false;
        }
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (isMousOver == true)
        {
            if (isPressed == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture3, rectangle, Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture2, rectangle, Color.White); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture1, rectangle, Color.White);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But i first need to set the currentMouseState before using it, and the lastMouseState should be pressed and currentMousestate should be Released or am i wrong?

Comment: You can always try this and if it does not work, then try it the other way around :)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand but what my codes does is, when u click the button while your mouse is on the button then it says this.isclicked = true.

Comment: I tried everything but i guess it will not work because currentState and lastState are always the same...

Comment: OK... thx to your help i figured out how to do it... i had to declare the currentMouseState and the lastMouseState as a class-variable and then i was able to use them correctly :3

Comment: I added my complete working Button-Class to your answer so people can get it :3